# Is the NFL's Mechanics Manual publically available?

Tags: american-football, officiating, nfl

The National Football League (NFL) publishes their [Rulebook online](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2022-nfl-rulebook/) and updates it each year. This defines all aspects of gameplay, penalties, and numerous other topics.

One topic I have been interested in is how Officials are supposed to conduct themselves during game play and what guidance they are given from the NFL in carrying out their duties. However, there is not much to go on... the only thing I can find in the Rulebook is

> Rule 19. Officials
>
> Section 1 - Officials
>
> Article 4. Responsibilities and Mechanics
>
> Officiating responsibilities and mechanics are specified in the **Mechanics Manual**, published annually by the National Football League.

**I cannot find the referred to "Mechanics Manual" on the NFL Operations website. Is it published publically or only internally by the NFL? If publically, where can I view it or obtain a copy from?**

Answer (score 3):

No. It is not publicly available.

Some alternatives might be

[Manual of Football Officiating (18th edition, perfect bound)](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=FlzIDwAAQBAJ)

https://www.nfhs.org/media/869192/2011-3-official-football-mechanics.pdf <--- This is for high school.

Comment: Most recent edition right from the source can be found here: http://www.myiafoa.org/

Comment: Hm... I think your link is the publications by International American Football Officials Association, not by the NFL.

Comment: Yes, I was commenting on your first link. which points to a Google Books site. The link I shared was to the direct IAFOA site.